# When I build the project .class files generated multiple times for the same .java file

Tags: java, spring-boot

When I build the Spring Boot project it generates the .class files multiple times for the same .java file. It causes `NoSuchMethodException`
[image]

Comment: What causes `NoSuchMethodException`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each of these `.class` files represents a different class. `KdmOrderService$1.class` was generated for [anonymous inner class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) defined inside the `KdmOrderService`.